# Page Object Model: need help with tests that uses more than 1 page object - Appium-Java-TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium, page-objects, page-factory

I have a framework based on POM model. I am able to write test that only uses elements from 1 page but when I need to access elements from another page tests fail because I think it uses the wrong driver since I am creating 2 drivers in the test and looks like that's the problem.

Also any help or opinion on making the framework a little better to optimize Page Object Model and PageFactory would be greatly appreciated!

I have AbstractScreen.java that has a constructor which initializes elements using AppiumFieldDecorator:

```
public class AbstractScreen extends DriverFactory {

  protected AndroidDriver driver;

  public AbstractScreen(AndroidDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
  }
}
```

I have DriverFactory.java that prepares the device:

```
public class DriverFactory {
  protected static AndroidDriver driver;

  @BeforeClass
  // Android device details
  public void configureSessionForDevice() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", Device.platformVersion);
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", Device.deviceName);
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Device.platformName);
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", Device.udid);
    capabilities.setCapability("app", Device.appDir);
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", Device.appPackage);
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", Device.appActivity);
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(Device.URL), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void killAppiumSession() {
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

I have WelcomeScreen.java:

```
public class WelcomeScreen extends AbstractScreen {
  public WelcomeScreen(AndroidDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
  }

  @AndroidFindBy(id = "button1")
  AndroidElement loginToYourAccountButton;
  @AndroidFindBy(id = "button2")
  AndroidElement continuesAsGuestButton;
  @AndroidFindBy(id = "welcome_to_text")
  AndroidElement welcomeToTextView;
  @AndroidFindBy(id = "text")
  AndroidElement securelyMoveWelcomeTextView;
  @AndroidFindBy(id = "welcome_logo")
  AndroidElement WelcomeLogoImageView;

  public void clickLoginIBMButton() {
    loginToYourAccountButton.click();
  }

  public void clickGuestButton() {
    continuesAsGuestButton.click();
  }
}
```

I have AuthenticationScreen.java

```
public class AuthenticationScreen extends AbstractScreen {

  public AuthenticationScreen(AndroidDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
  }
  @AndroidFindBy(id = "button1")
  AndroidElement continueButton;
  @AndroidFindBy(id = "button2")
  AndroidElement findURLButton;
  @AndroidFindBy(id = "or_separator")
  AndroidElement orSeparator;
  @AndroidFindBy(id = "domain_text_view")
  AndroidElement ibmAspera;
  @AndroidFindBy(id = "domain_edit_text")
  AndroidElement organization;
  WebElement authenticationText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Authentication']"));

  public void enterOrganization(String org) {
    organization.setValue(org);
  }

  public void clickContinueButton() {
    continueButton.click();
  }
}
```

And the test I am trying to write to login. I need to use both page objects of welcomeScreen and authenticationScreen, but I don't think what I am doing is the correct strategy. Can you help me optimize it?

```
public class ClickLoginButton {
    private WelcomeScreen welcomeScreen;
    private AuthenticationScreen authenticationScreen;
    private String org = "testeng.qa";

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpPage() {
        welcomeScreen = new WelcomeScreen(driver);
        authenticationScreen = new AuthenticationScreen(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void ClickButton() throws Throwable {
        welcomeScreen.clickLoginIBMButton();
        authenticationScreen.enterOrganization(org);
    }
}
```

I tried to make ClickLoginButton test to extend AbstractScreen but it throws error that AbstractScreen doesn't have default constructor. Not even sure if that would help or not

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I worked with Java so my code suggestions are going to be more pseudo-code than full code.

That said, the way to handle this situation is to have your page object methods return the next page object you require. So your `clickLoginIBMButton()` method would become more like the following pseudo-code:

```
public AuthenticationScreen clickLoginIBMButton()
{
    loginToYourAccountButton.click();
    return new AuthenticationScreen(driver);
}
```

Then your test code would change to be more like the following:

```
public class ClickLoginButton {
    private WelcomeScreen welcomeScreen;
    private AuthenticationScreen authenticationScreen;
    private String org = "testeng.qa";

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpPage() {
        welcomeScreen = new WelcomeScreen(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void ClickButton() throws Throwable {
        authenticationScreen = welcomeScreen.clickLoginIBMButton();
        authenticationScreen.enterOrganization(org);

        /* Note that you could also code this in the fluent style -
           welcomeScreen.clickLoginIBMButton().enterOrganization(org);
           If enterOrganization() returns the next page in the sequence
           you can then use that page object for your assertion
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Kate thanks for the help! I edited my code to return page object methods but i think it needs a little bit more correction. After editing my clickLoginIBMButton() method to what you said I get an error on this line:
        authenticationScreen = welcomeScreen.clickLoginIBMButton();
saying that "expected is AppPages.AuthenticationScreen but found void"
I will edit my code little bit more thanks for the push towards right direction! 
Also thanks for formatting my code :)